# Fail Load Data Fixtures Django - integer out of range

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm developing app using Django and Postgre.

Basically, I create new model on my app.

```
from django.db import models
from manager.models.state import State
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Address (models.Model):
 address_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 address_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
 address_city = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 address_phone = models.IntegerField()
 address_postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, default = 0)
 state =  models.ForeignKey(State, null=True, blank=True, default = None)
 user = models.ForeignKey(User,  null=True, blank=True, default = None)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.address_id

@classmethod
def get_list(cls):
    return list(cls.objects.values())
```

After that I run makemigrations and migrate commandline. All of the models are created on database normally.

I successfully load data from other json file (fixtures). 
When I tried to loaddata address.json on Address table, I got this error.

The Error Message:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/eeldwin/Documents/Django/fbt/manager/fixtures/address.json': Could not load manager.Address(pk=1): integer out of range
```

The Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django  /core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
   utility.execute()
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
   self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
   self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
   output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 61, in handle
   self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 91, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 148, in load_label
    obj.save(using=self.using)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 173, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 617, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 679, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 723, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 600, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1004, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/eeldwin/.virtualenvs/fbt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/eeldwin/Documents/Django/fbt/manager/fixtures/address.json': Could not load manager.Address(pk=1): integer out of range
```

Here's my fixtures

```
[{
"model": "manager.address",
"pk": 1,
"fields": {
  "address_id": "1",
  "address_name": "Jalan Muara Mas Timur 242",
  "address_city": "Semarang",
  "address_phone": "087832270893",
  "address_postcode": "3122",
  "state": "1"
}}]
```

However, when I inserted data to database manually, it will run perfectly. Any ideas what's happened here? Thanks.

Comment: Please show error message(not only traceback)

Comment: The error is Could not load manager.Address(pk=1): integer out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store `address_phone` as `IntegerField`. Its max value is 2147483647 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#integerfield).

But in your fixtures you try to add `087832270893` as `address_phone`, that why you receive `integer out of range` error.